# Insert XML data SQL Server - Encoding issue

Tags: .net, sql-server, xml, encoding

I serialize some data before inserting it into the DB.

```
Dim insertString As String = "INSERT INTO GP_SELECTION(SOCIETE, NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, DATA) VALUES ('{0}','{1}',{2},'{3}')"
Dim xmlData As String = .XmlFromFilters()
insertString = String.Format(insertString, societe, .Name, CInt(.ObjectType), xmlData)
```

Now, when I do the insert, the sql is like

```
INSERT INTO GP_SELECTION(SOCIETE, NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, DATA) VALUES ('01','hello world!!!',0,
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfPropertyFilter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PropertyFilter>
    <AndOr>SOME DATA</AndOr>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string" />
  </PropertyFilter>
</ArrayOfPropertyFilter>')
```

and the SQl server gives me:

> **XML parsing: line 1, character 38, unable to switch the encoding**

I wonder how to avoid it... Should I convert the Unicode(UTF) `insertString` ? How? Or maybe I should use a SQL method for conversion?

Maybe a solution will be to remove from the serialized string the "`encoding="utf-16"`" (then the insert works without problems)...?

**PS.** To prevent unusual comments, actually, I don't use stored procedures and I use the direct INSERT code. I recognize this is not the best way to do, but however this is my choice at this time.

Comment: Sorry - my close vote is uncalled for - your problem is a bit different from mine I had .....

Comment: What is the SQL Server version ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this makes a difference :-) but if you cast your XML to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and then back to `XML` it seems to work (at least in my test case):

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (ID INT, XmlCol XML)

INSERT INTO @tmp 
VALUES (1, CAST(CAST('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
                      <ArrayOfPropertyFilter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                         <PropertyFilter>
                              <AndOr>SOME DATA</AndOr>
                              <Value xsi:type="xsd:string" />
                         </PropertyFilter>
                      </ArrayOfPropertyFilter>' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XML))
```

Your **bigger** problem however is that your approach is open to SQL injection - you should use a **parametrized query** instead of concatenating together your SQL statement as a string!

Use something like:

```
INSERT INTO GP_SELECTION(SOCIETE, NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, DATA) 
VALUES (@Societe, @Name, @ObjectType, @Data)
```

and then define SQL parameters for your query and fill those with values. Much safer!!